# Twilio Video - switch media devices option not working

Tags: twilio, twilio-functions, twilio-video

I am using `twilio` with `twilio-video` v `beta-2` counting on the master branch of this repohttps://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-js

I got to display the select media and push the devices into it but when I am trying to updateVideoDevice I got an error

```
updateVideoDevice error TypeError: track must be a LocalAudioTrack, LocalVideoTrack, LocalDataTrack, or MediaStreamTrack
at Object.INVALID_TYPE (index.js:30952)
at Object.validateLocalTrack (index.js:31469)
at LocalParticipant.unpublishTrack (index.js:17047)
at index.js:17096
at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
at LocalParticipant.unpublishTracks (index.js:17095)
at index.js:36056
```

my `updateVideoDevice` function is as the following

```
function updateVideoDevice(event) {
const select = event.target;
const localParticipant = room.localParticipant;
if (select.value !== '') {
    Video.createLocalVideoTrack({
        deviceId: { exact: select.value }
    }).then(function(localVideoTrack) {
        const tracks = Array.from(localParticipant.videoTracks.values());
        localParticipant.unpublishTracks(tracks);
        log(localParticipant.identity + " removed track: " + tracks[0].kind);
        detachTracks(tracks);

        localParticipant.publishTrack(localVideoTrack);
        log(localParticipant.identity + " added track: " + localVideoTrack.kind);
        const previewContainer = document.getElementById('local-media');
        attachTracks([localVideoTrack], previewContainer);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('updateVideoDevice error' ,error);
    });
}
}
```

can any one explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

This looks to be a breaking change between Twilio Video JS v1 and v2. In the v2 documentation, calling [`localParticipant.videoTracks`](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/2.0.0-beta2/docs/LocalParticipant.html) returns a `Map` of `<Track.SID, LocalVideoTrackPublication>`. Calling `.values()` on that map returns an iterator of [`LocalVideoTrackPublication`](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/2.0.0-beta2/docs/LocalVideoTrackPublication.html)s which is then turned to an array using `Array.from`.

The issue is that you then pass that array of `LocalVideoTrackPublication`s to `localParticipant.unpublishTracks(tracks);` which causes the error because `unpublishTracks` expects an array of `LocalTrack`s not `LocalVideoTrackPublication`s.

You could fix this by mapping over the publications and returning the `track` property:

```
const tracks = Array.from(localParticipant.videoTracks.values())
                 .map(publication => publication.track);
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: thanks, this actually works, but only on ios safari browser. it doesn't work on android at all, not on chrome or firefox, the switch detaches and attaches a new track of the same camera?!

Comment: That sounds like a different problem now. Is there more debugging you can do and then ask a new question?

Comment: the error is, `NotReadableError: could not start a video source`

Comment: Have you also raised an issue on my GitHub repo about this? Perhaps we can work on it there instead?